# How to fix "zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element Value"

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am integration Endicia SOAP and I got this error:

```
"Missing element %s" % (self.name), path=render_path)
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element
Value (GetPostageLabel.LabelRequest.Value)
```

And here are my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from zeep import Client, Settings, xsd
from zeep.exceptions import Fault, TransportError, XMLSyntaxError

# Set Connection
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(
'https://elstestserver.endicia.com/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx?wsdl',
settings=settings)

# Set label request dictionary
requestDictionary = {
    "MailClass": 'Priority',
    "WeightOz": 16,
    "RequesterID": '',
    "AccountID": '',
    "PassPhrase": '',
    "PartnerCustomerID": '100',
    "PartnerTransactionID": '200',
    "ToName": 'Margaret D Norris',
    "ToAddress1": '2461  Romano Street',
    "ToCity": 'Cambridge',
    "ToState": 'MA',
    "ToPostalCode": '02141',
    "FromCompany": 'Camilla R Goforth',
    "FromName": 'Camilla R Goforth',
    "ReturnAddress1": '1670  Oliverio Drive',
    "FromCity": 'Satanta',
    "FromState": 'KS',
    "FromPostalCode": '67870',
    "CostCenter":'0'
}



# Try operation
try:
    response = client.service.GetPostageLabel(LabelRequest=requestDictionary)
    print(response)


except Fault as error:
    print(ET.tostring(error.detail))
```

Can anyone help?

I've tried to change the input data structure but it won't help
I expect the output of `response = client.service.GetPostageLabel(LabelRequest=requestDictionary)` and `print(response)` to be something like it shows on [this page](https://www.endicia.com/developer/docs/v8.9.html#create-label).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked says:

> RequesterID is required to specify who is making the request.

Your `requestDictionary` has an item for RequesterID:

```
...
"RequesterID": '',
...
```

Your error is saying

> **Missing element Value** (GetPostageLabel.LabelRequest.Value)

I think you are missing a value for RequesterID.